# How to fix connectivity pugin error on runtime?

Tags: dart, flutter

The application running well-using `flutter run`
**But**
using `flutter build apk`and `flutter install` app is not running well.

```
in terminal error message showing
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.3s
```

> Red color test below

```
Note: /Users/bhanukaisuru/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.2+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: read https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29770

Comment: Its not having any solution